# Calculate the percentage change with respect to the previous month

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

My database has information on a taxi service. I need to create a statement in sql code (I am working with mysql) that determines the percentage variation in the number of registered services with respect to the previous month.

I have the column that is of type date: "tpep_pickup_datetime" and has the following format 2020-01-01 00:33:03.

As in the first month there is no one with whom to compare, the result must be NULL in the column "variacion_mes_anterior", I don't know how to do it.

The code sentence that I am using and that does not work for me is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m') as mes, COUNT(id) as servicios,
CONCAT(
( SELECT TRUNCATE((count(test.id)/count(t.id) -1) *100, 0)
  FROM test AS t
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m')
 LIMIT 1
) , "%") as variacion_mes_anterior
FROM test
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m');
```

Example:

| id | tpep_pickup_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 00:33:03 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 00:33:03 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 00:33:03 |
| 3 | 2020-02-01 00:33:03 |
| 4 | 2020-02-02 00:33:03 |
| 5 | 2020-02-03 00:33:03 |
| 6 | 2020-02-04 00:33:03 |

This would be expected by a valid sql statement for my problem

| mes | servicios | variacion_mes_anterior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 3 | NULL |
| 2020-02 | 4 | 33% |

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: `variacion_mes_anterior` for `2020-02` is 100% because the difference between current and previous month (2000-1000=1000) is equal to previous month value (`100% * (2000-1000)/1000`)? Use some rough values.

Comment: @Akina yes, that's exactly what I want to apply to my problem, but my sql code doesn't work for me

Comment: `variacion_mes_anterior = CONCAT(100 * (servicios / LAG(servicios) OVER (ORDER BY mes) - 1), '%')`. Of course, replace output columns names with their expressions.

Comment: @Sergey modify the question and add an example

Comment: @Akina It doesn't work for me yet, could you show me the sql code as it would be? It should also be grouped by month

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT mes, 
       servicios, 
       CONCAT(ROUND(100 * (servicios / LAG(servicios) OVER (ORDER BY mes) - 1)), '%') variacion_mes_anterior
FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m') mes,
              COUNT(*) servicios
       FROM test
       GROUP BY mes ) subquery
ORDER BY mes;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=009c5f9cd2abad25f35295f60636e24b)